# How to interchange two links on their click jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="applications-wrapper">
    <div class="bar" id="onetwo"><a class="fa fa-bars" href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="eye" id="twothree"><a class="fa fa-eye" href="#"></a></div>
</div>
```

Here I want to swap the div having class bar and eye and on clicking the links the content related to it should also be shown and only the link on left when clicked should result in interchange.

[image]

Comment: And your script is? I think you only need to toggle classes

Comment: What do you want to swap ? The link or  the content ?

Comment: the links.. How can we use addClass and removeClass in this problem?

Comment: Where is the links? You have only anchor tag

Comment: oops sorry..By links I mean anchor tag only

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Here is the working code to exchange the anchor tags.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready");
   $( "#onetwo" ).click(function() {
    var temp = $(this).html();
     $(this).html($("#twothree").html()); 
    $("#twothree").html(temp);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="applications-wrapper">
    <div class="bar" id="onetwo"><a class="fa fa-bars" href="#">Link1</a></div>
    <div class="eye" id="twothree"><a class="fa fa-eye" href="#">Link2</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `removeClass` and `addClass` you can achive it.Please look at the code snippet below

```
      function ToogleClasses() {
        if ($('#onetwo a').hasClass("fa-bars")) {
            $('#onetwo a').removeClass("fa-bars").addClass("fa-eye");
        }
        else {
            $('#onetwo a').removeClass("fa-eye").addClass("fa-bars");
        }

        if ($('#twothree a').hasClass("fa-bars")) {
            $('#twothree a').removeClass("fa-bars").addClass("fa-eye");
        }
        else {
            $('#twothree a').removeClass("fa-eye").addClass("fa-bars");
        }
    }

    $('#onetwo').click(function () {
        ToogleClasses();
    });

    $('#twothree').click(function () {
        ToogleClasses();
    });
```

another solution will be

```
function ToogleClasses() {
    $('#onetwo a').toggleClass("fa-bars fa-eye");
    $('#twothree a').toggleClass("fa-bars fa-eye");
}
```

As the @OP wants the swapping should happen only when the link on left is cliked.Then code related to `$('#twothree a')`  should be commented

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#onetwo').click(function(){
    $('#onetwo').show();
    $('#twothree').hide();
});

$('#twothree').click(function(){
    $('#twothree').show();
    $('#onetwo').hide();
});
```

Comment: no it will not work for me.. here I want to interchange the two divs and the link present on the left when clicked should only result in the interchange

Comment: what u want please clarify . i didn't get you .

Comment: OP wants *Here I want to swap the div* `swap` and `hide and show` are not the same

Comment: If i click on the right icon it should not swap the divs eye and bar but if the click is on the left icon it should interchange the divs